# Can canvas check if user has liked a certain page?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible for canvas to check if user has liked a certain page **without** requesting `user_likes` extended permission? I have the `page_id` I need to check against.

I know it's entirely possible in a page tab as the check is made against the page user is currently browsing, but what about canvas? I'd really hate to ask for extended permissions just for this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **no, there is no way for canvas to check if user has liked a certain page without requesting permissions**.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the **page_fan** table, using fql. But you do need permission.

> A Facebook user who likes a Page as represented in FQL.
>   The User object has an equivalent likes connection.
>   To read the **page_fan** table you need
>
> - any valid access_token if it is public (visible to anyone on Facebook).
> - **user_likes** permissions if querying the current user.
> - **friends_likes** permissions if querying a user's friend.

The above paragraph from [this Facebook doc page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) clearly states that you need the **user_likes** permission.
 Check out the link to see what info the tables contain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user_likes permission (or if the user has public likes) the quickest way to check if a user likes a particular page is a call to `/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID` with that user's access token

I imagine most users' privacy will be set such that you need the `user_likes` permission though

Comment: I thought that Facebook requires the app to have the `user_likes` permission in order to check the pages he's a fan of, regardless of his privacy?

Comment: Sorry, you may be right, I was looking at the old pages.isFan doc which said it's only needed if the user's likes aren't public, but it's possible the Graph API version requires that permission even when checking for a specific page ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/ )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick, how you could solve this and we used it before. I know this is not a really clean and nice solution, but it works.

You need to create a **session** to save a **boolean variable** called $is_fan in it. On your canvas page you check if this param is available. On init it is not available so you redirect to your fanpage using the **app_data** param to pass, that the $is_fan has to be checked. On your fanpage you can **check then if the user is fan and save it to the session**. Then redirect to the canvas page.
in my browser the two redirects take about 1-2 seconds, which was ok for me...

Not an nice solution, but it works....